# Critical point on the boundary curve is not a critical point of the function.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

I am trying to find the max and min of the function:

$$f(x,y) = 1 + xy - x - y$$

over the region $D$ bounded by $y = x^2$ and $y = 4$.

First, I found when the partial derivatives are 0, which gives us the first critical point $(0,0)$.

Next, I have tried to parameterize the boundary curve $y = x^2$:

Let $x = t$ and $y = t^2$. This leaves us with the new function:

$$f \circ r(t) = 1 + t^3 - t - t^2$$

Differentiating and setting to 0 leaves us with:

$$t(t-2) = 0$$
$$\Rightarrow t = 0, 2$$

Substituting back into $x = t$ means we have critical points at $(0,0)$ and $(2, 4)$ on the boundary curve.

However, this doesn't seem right, as looking at the function plot:

[image]

This doesn't appear to be a max / min or saddle point.

Have I made a mistake somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did is correct, there is no need for the point (where you attains the max/min) on the bounday must be the critical points (max/min/saddle). The boundary is like to truncate the function before it reaching its natural critical points.

For example, let's see a single variable function $f=x^2$, if you set boundary as $-2\le x\le -1$, you get the max at $x=-2$ and min at $x=-1$, but none of them are the critical points of the function, because you truncate the function before it reaches its natural critical point $x=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Setting $f_x=0$ gives $y-1=0\Rightarrow y=1$.

Setting $f_y=0$ gives $x-1=0\Rightarrow x=1$.

So there is a critical point at $f(1,1)=0$ lying in the domain and also on the boundary  $y=x^2$.

Any other critical points *must* lie on the boundary.

For the boundary $y=x^2$, $f(x,x^2)=x^3-x^2-x+1$ which has critical points at $x=1$ and $x=-\frac{1}{3}$.

We previously found critical point $f(1,1)=0$, and now we have critical point $f\left(-\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{9}\right)=\frac{32}{27}$.

Finally, for boundary $y=4$,$f(x,4)=3x-3$. So the surface varies linearly along this boundary with a minimum value at $f(-2,4)=-9$ and a maximum value of $f(2,4)=9$.

So the minimum value of the function over domain $D$ is $-9$ at $(-2,4)$ and the maximum value is $9$ at $(2,4)$.

[image: Graph of domain]